# How can I check if the format is valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/m8sv89tg/1/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<input class="" type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" maxlength="10" placeholder="1234567890">
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.valid{
  border:1px solid green;
}
.invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$( "#primary_phone" ).blur(function() {
        text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '($1)$2-$3');
        $(this).val(text);

    if(the form==valid)
    {
       addClass.(valid);
    }else{
      addClass.(invalid);
   }

});
```

what I want to do is validate your ... to add a red border in case it is misspelled and the format is not respected.

I put in code idea how I want to do
If the user types the correct form first and then delete and write it wrong, I want to invalidate the code.

If you need more information please let me know

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `addClass.(valid);` **=>** `$(this).addClass.(valid);`

Answer (score 1):

make it (replace `.` by `:`), check [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/invalid/)

```
:valid{
  border:1px solid green;
}
:invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}

<input class="" type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" maxlength="10" placeholder="1234567890" pattern="(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)">
```

add `pattern` attribute as `(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)` so that browser knows what is `valid` and what is `invalid`

check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8sv89tg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can `regex.test()` to check the format is valid or not like following. It will return `true` if the format is valid and `false` if invalid.

```js
$("#primary_phone").blur(function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  if(text.length==13) return;
  
  var isValid = /(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/.test(text);
  if (isValid) {
    $(this).val(text.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '($1)$2-$3'));
    $(this).addClass('valid').removeClass('invalid');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('invalid').removeClass('valid');
  }
});
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="" type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" maxlength="10" placeholder="1234567890">
```